# Find-Replace text contained in textboxes and tables

Tags: replace, macros, textbox, translate

I'm hoping I can get come help from a programmer.

What I want to do is to translate a word report generated by a software, so I turned to macros. I already have a word file containing the original word/phrases and the translated ones.

I 'stole' the code to translate from some forum online, which works great with normal text. My problem is that the text of the report I want to translate is within various "text boxes" and "tables".

I was able to manually remove the tables, but keep the text. This totally ruined the formatting, but I can deal with that latter.
Now, unfortunately I cannot do the same with textboxes. There is no 'delete, but keep the text" function for textboxes.

I can send you the macro code, the original report automatically generated by the software and the file to get all translated words from.

I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Please do so: provide macro code and sample data. Of course, the code you "stole" and will paste here must be free for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is code that translates normal text.

```
Sub Translate()
Dim oChanges As Document, oDoc As Document
Dim oTable As Table
Dim oRng As Range
Dim rFindText As Range, rReplacement As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim sFname As String
'Change the path in the line below to reflect the path of the table document
sFname = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dictionary.doc"
Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
Set oChanges = Documents.Open(FileName:=sFname, Visible:=False)
Set oTable = oChanges.Tables(1)
For i = 1 To oTable.Rows.Count
Set oRng = oDoc.Range
Set rFindText = oTable.Cell(i, 1).Range
rFindText.End = rFindText.End - 1
Set rReplacement = oTable.Cell(i, 2).Range
rReplacement.End = rReplacement.End - 1
With oRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        Do While .Execute(findText:=rFindText, _
            MatchWholeWord:=True, _
            MatchWildcards:=False, _
            Forward:=True, _
            Wrap:=wdFindContinue) = True
            oRng.Text = rReplacement
        Loop
End With
Next i
oChanges.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

I'm guessing you'd need to see the format of the document that is being translated, which contains all the tables and text boxes. But it is too large and I'm not sure if I can send it as an attachment here somehow. (sorry, its my first time on this forum). Any advise?

Thanks a lot
JD